# Rspec - Check that a field is of type json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In Rails I have a field that is supposed to save json data. It's of type json. My current Rspec is as follows:

```
  it 'My field has some json data saved' do
    person = People.last
    saved_national_id_data = JSON.parse(person.raw_national_id_data)
    # check some attributes have proper data
  end
```

Now here I'm assuming that the field is json. **Is there a way in Rspec to check that the returned data for this field is of type json? Example:**

```
expect(saved_national_id_data).to be_json
```

Comment: There's no JSON type. Unparsed JSON is a string, parsed JSON is a Hash in Ruby. Answer below is a good direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it like this:

```
unparsable_json = ":a => 'b'"
expect { JSON.parse(unparsable_json)}.to_not raise_error
# It will return: RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected no Exception, got #<JSON::ParserError: 859: unexpected token at ':ok => 'a''

parsable_json = "\"ok\""
expect{JSON.parse(parsable_json)}.to_not raise_error
# It will pass the test
```

Comment: This is definitely a good direction, especially if JSON comes from and external system. It's possible to go further than that, and do something like `expect(JSON.dump(JSON.parse(person.raw_national_id_data))).to eq person.raw_national_id_data` to make sure that this JSON deserializes and serializes to the same thing. It is pretty strict though so you may run into issues.

Comment: Another way would be to apply some kind of JSON schema https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?q=json+schema

Comment: Thanks Mehmet this will do, and thanks @MikeSzyndel for the suggestions